# How to concatenate text and a number next after a number in a list in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to concatenate a text and a number next after it in a list using python.My input lists are given below:

```
a= ["hello", "hello", "1", "hello", "2"]
b= ["hello", "hello", "1"]
c= ["hello", "1"]
```

my desired output :

```
a= ["hello", "hello 1", "hello 2"]
b= ["hello", "hello 1"]
c= ["hello 1"]
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using regex from the `re` library. Also I advise to have a look at [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/) to build the regex you need and test it, to get an understanding on how they work

```py
import re

a= ["hello", "hello", "1", "hello", "2"]

a = [i.replace(' ', '') for i in re.findall('\w+\s*\d*',' '.join(a))]

>>>print(a)
['hello', 'hello1', 'hello2']
```